# Change of RGB LED to cheaper one

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, rgb

Right now I'm reading [Raspberry Pi Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029595.do) and I would like to create the program described in the book. Because I'm beginner and I would like to buy more (cheaper) RGB LEDs at once and also I will get them faster than the ones from link in book, so I need some help. The author of the book wrote that along of [Diffused LED - RGB 10mm from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11120) I need three 1k ohm resistors. The problem is that I would like to buy RGB LEDs from [DX](http://www.dx.com/p/jtron-5mm-4-pin-rgb-full-color-led-common-cathode-transparent-10-pcs-284320#.VGjNyWdNf-s) or [Banggood](http://www.banggood.com/10pcs-5mm-RGB-LED-Common-Cathode-4-Pin-Tri-Color-Emitting-Diodes-F5-p-937475.html) which are also smaller, but I don't know if I can use them with my Raspberry Pi and 1k ohm resistors because there are some differences between voltages looking at Sparkfun and DX/Banggood.

Basically I just need to know if I can use RGB LEDs from DX or Banggood with 1k ohm resistors and if there will not be any problem because of different voltages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine with just about any small LEDs you get. According to the [Raspberry Pi GPIO guide](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/), they put out 3.3V when turned on, which is more than enough for the other LEDs you linked to. As long as you don't forget to put the resistors in series with the LEDs to limit the current, they should work just fine.

There will be a difference in appearance since the Sparkfun LEDs are diffused plastic and the other ones you linked are clear, but that's a matter of your preferences. They should light up without a problem.